# when hitting ENTER then it moves to the input on the row BELOW the current focus row in the repeating group in Bubble.io

Tags: javascript, bubble.io

IN THE BUBBLE.IO when hitting ENTER then it moves to the input on the row BELOW the current focus row in the repeating group
THIS IS THE MAIN PROBLEM I AM FACING
How to focus on next row input in the same column by hitting enter key

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to bound it by giving it the current cells repeating groups id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).